# cURL Not Working Properly With PHP In Some Instances, Connection refused

Tags: php, curl

I've run into a very strange issue. I have two of the exact same devices at different locations. One device belongs to me and one to a customer. I am trying to run an api request on the devices via php and it runs perfectly all of the time on my device and failed with refused to connect on the customer's device. The part where it gets strange is that the device that failed is working if I use postman or the curl tool at (https://reqbin.com/curl) to send the command, it just doesn't want to do it via php for some reason and says

> "Failed to connect to 8.8.8.8 port 11443: Connection refused"

.
Here's the curl command that I ran that was working (IP has been substituted by placeholder and base64 abridged since it was super long)

```
curl -k --location --request POST "https://8.8.8.8:11443/api/v1/face/addPerson" --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data-raw '{"groupId":"DA640D7CE7544B33A3A1C81CD95D3E66","userId":"12345","name":"Test Human","age":30,"gender":"male","phone":"18200000000","email":"foo@bar.com","certificateType":111,"certificateNumber":"310101199003078299","updateTime":"20200331123025","images":[{"data":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/"}],"accessInfo":{"cardNum":"","password":"","authType":0,"roleType":0}}'
```

PHP:

```
<?php
function createUser($URL)
{
    echo "Adding person at: " . $URL;
    $base64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLC7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozv/wAARCAFTASwDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAABAAEFAQEAAAAAAA";
    

    $gender = "male";

    $data = "
    {
        \"groupId\": \"DA640D7CE7544B33A3A1C81CD95D3E66\",

        \"userId\": \"12345\",

        \"name\": \"Zhang San\",

        \"age\": 30,

        \"gender\": \"$gender\",

        \"phone\": \"18200000000\",

        \"email\": \"foo@bar.com\",

        \"certificateType\": 111,

        \"certificateNumber\": \"310101199003078299\",

        \"updateTime\": \"20200331123025\",

        \"images\": 
        [

            {
                \"data\": \"$base64\"
            }
        ],

        \"accessInfo\": 
        {
            \"cardNum\": \"\",
            \"password\": \"\",
            \"authType\": 0,
            \"roleType\": 0
        }
    }";

    $curl = curl_init();

    $headers = array
    (
        'Content-type: application/json'
    );

    //items added to try to fix connection refused error
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.41");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//less secure, but needed for self-signed certificate
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);//less secure, but needed for self-signed certificate
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS , false);//less secure, but needed for self-signed certificate        
    $response= curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if ($err) 
    {
        print "<br><br>cURL Error: $err";// \n\n Data: \n$data
    }
    $response = json_decode($response);
    if($response)
    {       
        if ($response->status == 0)
        {
            echo "success";
        }
        else
        {
            
            print_r($response);
        }
    }
}

createUser("https://8.8.8.8:11443/api/v1/face/addPerson");
?>
```

Comment: Probably need `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` in the PHP, your CMD has it. You also should create the JSON with PHP, not by hand. Will be easier to read and alter later.

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you for the suggestion. Per the suggestion, I tested with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  set to true and to false and unfortunately still got connection refused by both.